# How to get 3D objects to orbit with camera rotation

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I just started getting into three.js and I have a camera which is pinned to 0,0,0 and can rotate around 360 degrees. I have an 3D object which starts off in front of the camera and which I'd like to have orbit around the camera in tangent with the camera's rotation so that essentially the 3D object never leaves the camera's sight

The code for the camera is pretty standard

```
    phi     = TDP.toRadians( 90 - lat );    
    theta   = TDP.toRadians( lon );         

    camera.target.x = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
    camera.target.y = Math.cos( phi );
    camera.target.z = Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
```

As for the code that updates the 3D object

```
    arrow.position.x = - Math.sin( TDP.toRadians( lon ) ) * camera.target.x + arrow.position.x;
    arrow.position.z = Math.cos( TDP.toRadians( lon ) ) * camera.target.z + arrow.position.z;
```

I've just been playing around with this equation and am stuck math-wise. The movement of the object along the x axis kind of works but the z position is way off. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking wayyy too hard about this problem. Probably due to lack of sleep but I solved it anyway. In case anyone has similar problems all you have to do is change the positions to

`arrow.position.x = camera.target.x * distance_from_camera;
    arrow.position.z = camera.target.z * distance_from_camera;`